# Javascript add month to variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a variable in Javascript such as:

```
var a = "2015/05/04";
```

How do I add/subtract months to the variable such as:

```
a.getMonths() + 1;
```

that will result in "2015/06/04"

I tried to do the getMonths() and the alert is not displaying the result.

Comment: Can you used moment for it?

Comment: `a` is a string. Try creating a date from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a date object and add months as shown:

```
var a = new Date("2015/05/04");
a.setMonth(a.getMonth() + 1);  // add months
a.setMonth(a.getMonth() - 2);  // subtract months
```

**Example:**

```js
var a = new Date("2015/05/04");
print();

a.setMonth(a.getMonth() + 1);
print();

a.setMonth(a.getMonth() - 2);
print();

function print() {
   stdout.innerHTML += a.toISOString() + '\n'; 
}
```

```html
<pre id="stdout"></pre>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was missing setMonth attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At first you must include [moment.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js) on your page:

```js
var a = "2015/05/04";
var date = moment(a, "YYYY/MM/DD");
date.add(1, 'months')
var result = date.format("YYYY/MM/DD");+
alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Next, implement that algorithm. IMHO it the easiest and the most correct way.

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, this is also a good alternative but I cannot use moment.js otherwise, this option would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to or can't use moment.js, here's a plain javascript approach:

```js
var a = "2015/05/04";
var dateparts = a.split("/");

var date = new Date(dateparts[0], dateparts[1], dateparts[2]);

date = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1));
console.log(date.getFullYear() + '/' +  date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or easier [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This may work out for you (https://jsfiddle.net/kL96nhfx/)

```
var a = "2015/05/04";
var res = '';

function editMonth(date, amount) {
   var dateSplit = date.split('/');
   var tmp = '';

   tmp = parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
   tmp += amount;


   if (tmp > 12) {
     dateSplit[1] = parseInt(tmp / 12);

     if (tmp < 10) {
         dateSplit[1] = '0' + tmp.toString(); 
     } else {
         dateSplit[1] = tmp.toString();
     }

 } else if (tmp <= 0) {
     tmp = 1;
     dateSplit[1] = '0' + tmp.toString(); 
 } else {
     dateSplit[1] = '0' + tmp.toString(); 
 }

 return dateSplit.join('/')
};

 res = editMonth(a, 1);
 console.log(res);
```

Only Moment.js is 129KB not compressed (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.js). Unless you're not doing anything specific IMHO I wouldn't use it. 
It's just useless overhead